# PageAdapter, findViewById return null, what's the other way

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have used PageAdapter as described by [this post](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/).

In one of my layout pages there's a ListView in which I want to add items at the run time. Normally I'd do:-

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

but that doesn't work as the ContentView is not set

**Is there any other way to get the listview**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the layoutinflator to get views which are not set by setContent view for example ListView lv = Layoutinflator.from(mContext).inflate(R.id.list, null);

Comment: Did that. Passed the MainActivity's application context but still findViewById(R.id.list); returns null